# SNowflake-Power BI connectivity Issue - CURLerror

Tags: curl, powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Power BI native connector for Snowflake. The snowflake account is a trial account . I am getting this CURL error . Has anybody been able to resolve the issue?

Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Snowflake] (4)
REST request for URL https://east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=49ae270c-0daa-4b32-a074-d6f5d2d0ba0a&request_guid=643e3694-2fd0-42ae-ba8e-3eb7a88e0e1c&warehouse=Compute_WH failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=60 msg='SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK' osCode=9 osMsg='Bad file descriptor'

Answer (score 1):

You have an SSL proxy in between that intercepts the communication between your client, PowerBi and Snowflake.

Solution is [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/CURLerror-SSL-peer-certificate-or-SSH-remote-key-was-not-OK-during)